# .ajaxComplete prevent any callbacks calls. is it possible?

Tags: jquery

i have a backend written with php and a frontend on jQuery.. what i want to do:

1. page contains several links with AJAX calls (each one has it's own sucess/error callbacks)
2. php backend may return a reply something like this: {"must_relogin":true}
3. i have to bind to some kind global AJAX event in jQuery to catch this response and do perform some my logic and to prevent any other callbacks

is it possible?

Thank you for help.

**update**

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(a, b, c){ 
 console.log(a, b, c);
 b.abort();
 return false; });
```

Comment: your ajax calls are synchronous or async?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`? It states "*Prevents other event handlers from being called*". From looking at the jQuery source we see this

```
if ( fireGlobals ) {
    globalEventContext.trigger( "ajaxComplete", [ jqXHR, s] );
    // Handle the global AJAX counter
    if ( !( --jQuery.active ) ) {
        jQuery.event.trigger( "ajaxStop" );
    }
}
```

Here is a working example of it potentially solving your problem, http://jsfiddle.net/Akkuma/95zfj/

The caveat is that it appears to not work if the ajaxCompletes are not all bound to the same element.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure about your scenario but here is a SO link

[Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/kill-ajax-requests-using-javascript-using-jquery)

that explains aborting the `ajax` calls using **`.abort`** but if a call is already made to the server then `.abort` cannot close an existing connection to the server, all the `success` call backs of the ajax calls that has been already made will be executed anyway...

HTH

Comment: my code: 
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(a, b, c){
   console.log(a, b, c);
   b.abort();
   return false;
  });
i do not want to close any opened connections or cancel any active requests - i just need to prevent success callbacks calls

Comment: you **cannot** cancel the ajax request in its `success` callback if you want to cancel it you have to do it before it is being initiated

Comment: ok.. once again :) i do not need to **cancel** ajax requests in success callbacks - i understand that this is impossible.

my solution is [http://pastebin.com/fDcTgqtd] but i can not post it as an answer because of my reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, it is not possible to prevent the callback calls based on the response string. The problem is that the ajax global event handlers like ajaxSuccess and ajaxComplete are called after the callbacks have been executed.